# Typescript file giving error if not included on tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript

I have the following file structure in my project:

```
- root
  - build
     - index.js
     - other files
  - src
     - index.ts
     - other files
  - postinstall.ts
  - tsconfig.json
```

I want to complie only files inside `src` folder to `build` dir and don't want to compile `postinstall.ts` file as it's only used after installing a new package in my project.

If I don't add `postinstall.ts` inside `include` section in `tsconfig.json` I can see errors when I open the file. Here's some errors I g:

```
Cannot find module 'fs' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
Cannot find module 'path' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
Cannot find name '__dirname'.ts(2304)
```

If I add it on `include` section then all errors on `postinstall.ts` are gone but now I have the error `'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.` in `tsconfig.json`.

Here's my `tsconfig.json` settings:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "removeComments": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./src/types"
    ],
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./*"
      ]
    },
    "outDir": "build",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false
  },
  "tsc-alias": {
    "resolveFullPaths": true,
    "verbose": false
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

How can I solve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can define another TS Config file for `postinstall.ts` that you may call `tsconfig.node.json` (like [Vite](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/blob/main/packages/create-vite/template-react-ts/tsconfig.node.json) does for their `vite.config.ts`):

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": ["postinstall.ts"]
}
```

And then you might use it with Typescript CLI with the following command:

```bash
tsc --project tsconfig.node.json
```

Comment: This doesn't work, I still have the erros on `postinstall.ts` file. If I inclue it on `tsconfig.json` then all errors it this file are gone but I have the error about `rootDir`. I also don't need to compile this file because I use `ts-node` to run it's content only after installing a new package on my project